# Como desativar todos os sons de um WebBrowser?

Tags: visual-basic-6, navegador-de-internet

Existe algum comando para desativar todos os sons de um `WebBrowser` no Visual Basic 2008? Gostaria de deixá-lo mudo para que não tocar os sons dos vídeos do Youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Não creio que seja viável controlar diretamente o player do YouTube pela sua linguagem, pois a tecnologia Flash executa em um ambiente isolado dentro da página. Até daria para fazer alguma gambiarra através de engenharia reversa, mas certamente seria arriscado e possivelmente não portável entre diferentes versões.

Entretanto, há uma forma de se comunicar com o flash através do JavaScript e que talvez você possa usar para atingir essa finalidade. 
Se o filme está embebido na página através do método oficial usando um **iframe**, você poderá usar o [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) para controlar o filme. Entnao basta injetar na sua página um script com o código `player.mute()` e terá o resultado esperado.

Porém, se o vídeo for adicionado por outro método isso não funcionará. Uma alternativa é abaixar o volume todo do PC usando a API do Sistema Operacional.

Comment: e como que eu posso fazer isso ?

Comment: pq eu estou usando o vb 2008, e da para eu adcionar o script no webbrowser? não entendir muito bem, se pode me explicar melhor eu te agradeço muito